# Are hybrid apps using Webview supported on all Android TV models?

Tags: android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app, android-tv

We wanted to check if it's ok to write a hybrid app (html5 app + native code) using Android web view and whether such an app can be loaded in all Android TV models. There are some posts which say users may have to install the Android Webview separately from PlayStore which we don't want. We want users to install the hybrid app running inside the Android webview from Playstore same as a native app with no extra installation required.

We wrote a hybrid app and tested it on an android tv simulator but we are not sure if such an app can be deployed directly from Playstore and will work on all Android TV models without any extra step needed just like any other android app.

Comment: What wrapper did you use for your hybrid app to make it run on Android/Android TV?

Comment: We have used 2 approaches: one is with cordova and another is a native code which has a webview.

Comment: I've answered with some initial details and advice. Let me know if you'd like more info!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, hybrid apps using a WebView are supported on the Google Play Store for Android TV devices.

Google's own YouTube app for Android TV uses [the Cobalt framework which is a HTML5 based](https://cobalt.foo/).

Also, on certified Android TV devices that come with the Google Play Store, WebView is always available and [updated regularly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)

#### Advice for publishing on Android TV (compared to Android phones)

1. Make sure your app works properly with a d-pad, either in the emulator or on a real device
2. Depending on the spec. of your Mac or PC, the emulator can run apps a lot faster than real devices. I advise you test on a cheap Android TV device such as the [Chromecast for Google TV](https://store.google.com/product/chromecast_google_tv), for example.
3. When you upload your app to the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console/), you must opt-in to have your app available for Android TV. Look in Release > Setup > Advanced Settings > Form factors (tab), click `+ Add form factor`.